# Optimizing Jquery iteration through table columns comparing with existing row

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to write a function to add color to a table based on a reference which is one of the top rows of the table. There are several questions in SO mentioning row based iteration but not so much about column.

The structure of the table is something like:

```
<table id="data">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Selection</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Title</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Info1</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Info2</th>
        <th colspan="10">Data</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>001</th>
        <th>002</th>
        <th>003</th>
        <th>004</th>
        <th>005</th>
        <th>006</th>
        <th>007</th>
        <th>008</th>
        <th>009</th>
        <th>010</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ref_control">
        <td></td>
        <td>RefName</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>J</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>Z</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>Entity 1</td>
        <td>Info...</td>
        <td>More info...</td>
        <td>Even more...</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>T</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>Z</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    (...)
</table>
```

In addition I'm using JQuery and the [JQuery column cell select plugin](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/column/) to perform the mentioned task.

The Javascript code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Colorize table based on matches
    // Number of Data entries - Count on the reference (2nd row)
    // and only 5th column onwards (index starts at 0)
    var datasize = $("#data tr:eq(2) td:gt(4)").length;

    // Start with column 6 (index starts at 1)
    var begin = 6;

    for (var i = begin; i < begin + datasize; ++i) {
        var curCol = $("#data td").nthCol(i);
        var ref = curCol.eq(0).text();
        curCol.not(curCol.eq(0)).each(function() {
            var data = $(this);
            if (data.text() == '') {
                data.addClass("black");
            } else if (data.text() != ref) {
                data.addClass("color");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

A working example can be visualized [here](http://jsbin.com/enezo3/3). In the example the table has only 9 rows and 10 data columns. The actual page I'm trying to optimize has 20 rows and 90 data columns.

Using the mentioned Javascript extensions/plugins the big sized table poses no threat to the Google Chrome browser taking a few seconds to load, however Opera, Firefox and Internet Explorer have a hard time running the function or end up asking for user interaction to stop the script from running.

So my question is aimed at both alternatives to the [column select plugin](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/column/) or ways to optimize the code such that I don't kill almost all browsers except Google Chrome.

**Edit**: Changes according the the two comments from @Pointy

Comment: Don't forget to declare "i" with `var` in your `for` loop!!!!

Comment: Also, setting "class" like that is not really a good idea - use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`.

Comment: @Pointy .attr() use was meant to replace all classes that could be attributed to the element. It's not considered a "bad idea" since it's the recommended way to do it in the JQuery docs.

Comment: and if we're getting nitpicky, use .length instead of .size!

Comment: @Unode well if that's what you really want. You could also just set the raw "className" attribute on the DOM too.  Personally I wish there were something like `.toggleClass()` that let me give a class for the `true` case and a different class for `false` ...

Comment: Oh also this is an interesting and (hopefully) beneficial question.

Comment: Also I checked the jQuery source and you're right about `attr("class")` - that should work just fine and I apologize for complaining about it ~ ~ ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get **[10x faster](http://jsperf.com/color-column)** code if you want. Just save references once and go row by row instead of column by column. It doesn't become more complicated yet it performs much better. The reason is that your plug-in hides the **abstraction** that your table is made of rows that are made of columns. And not the other way around. Emulating the second version can be **costy** as you noticed in this example.

You may also use DOM properties instead of jQuery methods. They are really straightforward.

```
// get text (modern browsers || IE <= 8)
var text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
// set class
elem.className = "black";
```

your final code will be something like:

```
var refcells = $("#data tr:eq(2) td:gt(4)");
var datasize = refcells.length;
// Start with column 5
var begin = 5;
var refs = [];
var i = begin;
refcells.each(function () {
  refs[i++] = $(this).text();
});

$("#data tr:gt(2)").each(function () {
  var cells = $("td", this);
  for (var i = begin; i < begin + datasize; i++) {
    var elem = cells[i];
    var text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
    if (!text) {
      elem.className = "black";
    } else if (text != refs[i]) {
      elem.className = "color";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I would just add a comment about what and why `elem.textContent || elem.innerText` is used  and your answer is perfect. Thumbs up!

Comment: Also why not use the DOM element on the refcells too? Minor perfomance increase but still faster - http://jsperf.com/color-column/3

Comment: I've updated the DOM text part, it's basically `modern browsers || IE <= 8`. Yes it can be used on the ref cells but their number is limited so it's minor gain. The real cells however are related to the row number and so they're much more important. I'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you're doing is going to be *very* computationally intensive.  Since your table layout seems pretty regular, I'd just completely ditch that `nthCol()` thing (for this page anyway) and do your work by iterating over the table **once**:

1. Grab the "key" row first, and save it
2. Loop through each relevant `<tr>`, and for each one get the `<td>` elements and iterate over them as a raw node list, or as a jQuery list.  Either way it should be a lot faster.
3. In the second loop, you'll do the same logic you've got (although I'd use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`), referring back to the saved "key" row for each cell.

In your current loop, you're re-building the jQuery object of *every* `<td>` in the table for each column, and *then* you're doing that `nthCol()` work! That's a lot of work to do if you do it **once**, so repeating that for every single column is going to really drag that CPU down. (On IE6 - especially with all those "class" changes - I bet it's almost unbearably slow.)

*edit* — I looked over that code (for the plugin), and while it looks like it was competently implemented it doesn't have any "magic tricks".  All it does is iterate through all the table cells you give it and checks whether or not each cell is in fact in the "nth" column. Thus, your iteration will perform that test on every cell in the table for every column you care about. In your 90x20 table, that'd be about 85 iterations through all 1800 cells. And that's *before* you do your work!